# Gast + Genitiv vs. Gast von

Tags: word-usage, preposition, genitive

Heute las ich auf einem "Begrüßungs-Bildschirm" folgende Formulierung, die mein Sprachgefühl irritiert hat:

> Werte Gäste der XYZ AG,
>
> herzlich Willkommen bei der ABC GmbH!

Der Bildschirm hängt im Foyer der ABC GmbH, die an diesem Tag eine Delegation von der XYZ AG erwartet hat.

Die "Gäste der XYZ AG" sind meinem Sprachgefühl nach *bei der XYZ-AG zu Besuch*. Müsste man in der vorliegenden Situation nicht "*von* der XYZ AG" schreiben? Das klingt für mich eher zutreffend, aber trotzdem ein wenig holprig.

Leider finde ich in den gängigen Wörterbüchern unter dem Lemma "Gast" keinen Beleg für mein Gefühl; Eine Google-Suche mit Kombinationen von "Gast" mit "Genitiv" und/oder "von" fördert nichts brauchbares zutage, und ich habe keine Idee, welche spezielle Art von Nachschlagewerk hier vielleicht in Betracht kommen könnte.

Kann jemand mein Gefühl bestätigen (oder auch widerlegen) und hat idealerweise irgendeine Fundstelle zum Nachschlagen?
Vielleicht gibt es auch eine elegantere Formulierung als "Werte Gäste *von* der XYZ AG"?

PS: Ob "Werte" als Anrede hier passend ist, ist ausdrücklich *nicht* Gegenstand dieser Frage.

### Nachtrag / Klarstellung:

Ich bin mir bzgl. folgender Aussagen sicher:

1. "Gäste der XYZ AG" *kann* Personen bezeichnen, die *bei* der XYZ AG zu Gast sind, und dies ist die *übliche* Bedeutung dieser Formulierung (aber auf die oben geschilderte Situation nicht zutreffend)
2. Die Formulierung "Gäste *von* der XYZ AG" macht es eindeutig, dass die XYZ AG die Herkunft der Gäste ist, und nicht als Gastgeber auftritt.

Meine Hauptfrage lautet (und mein Sprachgefühl sagt "nein"):

- Kann "Gäste der XYZ AG" auch ausdrücken, dass die Gäste *von* der XYZ AG kommen?
- Gibt es für die (positive oder negative Antwort) irgendwelche Belege?

Bonusfrage:

- Die Formulierung "Gäste *von* der XYZ AG" erscheint mir korrekt aber holprig. Gibt es eine elegantere Variante?

Comment: Was ist jetzt dein Gefühl? Dass es "Die Gäste von der XYZ-AG" heißen sollte? Dann täuscht dich dein Gefühl. Dies hört man zwar in nachlässiger Alltagsrede hin und wieder, doch schreiben sollte man es keinesfalls. Und selbst im Mündlichen würde es einen als wenig sprachgewandt brandmarken.

Comment: Danke für die Rückfrage. Ich habe meine Frage ergänzt, jetzt ist hoffentlich klar was gefragt ist.

Comment: Ah! Jetzt verstehe ich das. Es geht um "Gäste von der ABC-AG bei der XYZ-AG". Dann finde ich hast du recht mit deinem Gefühl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Kann "Gäste der XYZ AG" auch ausdrücken, dass die Gäste von der XYZ AG kommen?**

Warum nicht? Abweichend von der postulierten »üblichen Bedeutung« kann das Genitivattribut auch so verwendet werden:

> - Gäste der letzten Saison
> - Gäste der anderen Art
> - Gäste adliger Abstammung
> - Gäste außerirdischer Herkunft

Solange die Funktion des Attributs klar ist, gibt es keinen Grund, das mit einer Präpositionalgruppe oder einem Nebensatz zu präzisieren. Und da der Gastgeber in Deinem Fall ja offensichtlich bekannt ist, verursacht man auch bei der Herkunft der Gäste keine Missverständnisse.

**Gibt es für die (positive oder negative Antwort) irgendwelche Belege?**

Wohl kaum: Die verschiedenen Funktionen des Genitivattributs sind ja hinreichend bekannt. Vorsicht ist nur geboten, wenn die Bedeutung einer solchen Phrase unklar ist. Das hängt aber immer vom Kontext ab und lässt sich deshalb nicht in grammatische Regeln fassen.

Das Wort »Bild« ist ein plakatives Beispiel für das Risiko von Missverständnissen:

> - ein Bild des Louvre
> - ein Bild des jungen Picasso
> - ein Bild des Barocks
> - ein Bild des Matterhorns

In obigen Phrasen entscheidet einzig das Allgemeinwissen des Lesers, welche Funktion das Attribut hat.

Umgekehrt kann die Phrase

> - ein Bild des Präsidenten

allein durch ihren Kontext eindeutig werden (frei erfunden):

> - Heuss malte leidenschaftlich gern.
> - von Weizsäcker war Kunstsammler.
> - Scheel war sehr eitel.

Wenn die vielfältigen Funktionen des Genitivattributs beim Wort »Bild« keine Probleme bereiten, wieso sollte man sich dann bei »Gast« einschränken?

**Die Formulierung "Gäste von der XYZ AG" erscheint mir korrekt aber holprig. Gibt es eine elegantere Variante?**

Ein Genitivattribut kann oft durch eine Präpositionalgruppe mit *von* ersetzt werden (siehe [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Satzgliedbau/Nomen/Nomen.html#Anchor-Ersatz-47857)). Insofern ist »Gäste von der XYZ AG« korrekt (wenn auch weniger elegant). Die Präposition *von* klärt allerdings nicht die Funktion des Attributs und klappt genauso bei »Gäste der ABC GmbH«. Beispiel:

> - Die Gäste vom Hotel nebenan sind oft zu laut.

Um ausdrücklich die Herkunft der Gäste zu benennen, wäre die Präposition *aus* etwas treffender. Aber am besten fände ich, ein anderes Wort für »Gäste« zu wählen, welches mehr deren Herkunft fokussiert: »Mitarbeiter«, »Vertreter«, »Abgesandte« oder »Delegation«.

Comment: > Aber am besten fände ich, ein anderes Wort für »Gäste« zu wählen
Dieser Vorschlag (auf den ich wohl auch selbst hätte kommen können, aber leider nicht bin), führt dazu, dass ich diese Antwort akzeptieren werde. Das ist wohl die elegantest mögliche Lösung!

Answer (score 6):

Ohne dass ich dies nun eigens mit Verweisen auf Grammatikwerke belegen könnte, kann ich dir aus meinem Sprachgefühl als Muttersprachler (und beruflich auch immer wieder Publizierender) bestätigen, dass dein Gefühl richtig ist. Um die Gäste, die von der ABC-AG kommen, bei der XYZ-AG zu begrüßen, wäre es in der Tat am besten

> Werte Gäste von der ABC-AG, herzlich willkommen bei der XYZ-AG!

zu schreiben.

Rein von der Grammatik her wäre zwar auch

> ? Werte Gäste der ABC-AG, herzlich willkommen bei der XYZ-AG!

nicht falsch, aber da der Genitiv *Gäste der ABC-AG* auch so verstanden werden kann als meinte er "jene, die bei der ABC-AG zu Gast sind", ist es stilistisch und kommunikationstheoretisch besser, die eindeutige Form zu verwenden. Solche Plakate sollen ja auf einen Blick verständlich sein und also dem Leser möglichst wenig Stolpersteine in den Weg legen.

Allerdings hängt die Entscheidung für eine Formulierung auch vom jeweiligen Umfeld ab.

> Werte Gäste von Siemens, herzlich willkommen bei Bayer!

wäre jedenfalls die natürliche Variante in diesem Fall. Stolpersteinlose Begrüßungs-Plakate wären nach meinem Dafürhalten:

> Werte Gäste von der Deutschen Bahn, herzlich willkommen bei den Hannoveraner Verkehrsbetrieben.
>
> Werte Gäste aus den Pelikan-Werken, herzlich willkommen bei Faber-Castell.
>
> Liebe Gäste von Vattenfall, herzlich willkommen bei Greenpeace!
>
> Werte Gäste von der Schreinerei Tischbein, herzlich willkommen in der Tischlerei Steinmetz!

Comment: > ist es stilistisch und kommunikationstheoretisch besser, die eindeutige Form zu verwenden
Vielen Dank speziell für diesen Gedanken! Es geht ja nicht allein darum, wie der Satz nach den Regeln der Sprache verstanden werden kann/darf.

Comment: Es ist ja jedem immer klar, wer man ist und woher man kommt, und auch, wohin man gegangen/gefahren ist und warum - zumindest sollte es das ein. Deswegen kann es bei einer Begrüßungs-Anrede keine derartigen Missverständnisse geben, darauf kommt man erst, wenn man darauf gestoßen wird, dass das grammatisch-theoretisch möglich wäre. Daher halte ich die Genitiv-Varianten für unbedenklich und üblich, die _von_-Anschlüsse hingegen für ein wenig rustikal. Missverständnisse könnte es vielleicht im Falle mehrerer Einlader/Gästegruppen geben, aber selbst dann weiß man, ob Einlader oder Eingeladener ist.

Comment: ... Anders ist es in der dritten Person, aber auch wieder nur bei mehreren Einladern/Eingeladenen: _Für die Gäste der Bayer AG fand um 14.30 Uhr eine Präsentation der aktuellen Produktentwicklung statt._ Eine eindeutige Bestimmung der Referenz von '_der Bayer AG_' müsste hier durch den Textzusammenhang geliefert werden, was einem flüchtigen Leser schonmal 'durch die Lappen gehen' kann.

Comment: @RalfJoerres (1): Nicht zwingend. Um den Spitzfind zu geben: Eine große Messe, bei der die Firmen A und B viele Räume für ihre Mitarbeiter im gleichen Hotal angemietet haben, inkl. eines Konferenzraumes, um am Rande der Messe ... trallala. Vielleicht hat die Sparte "Laptops" Mitarbeiter der anderen Firma B eingeladen und als Mitarbeiter von A (Server) weißt Du nichts davon.